# Exporting a range of cells in Excel to Word and saving the Word document as both a Word-file AND a PDF-file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, pdf-generation

**What I am trying to do:**
Export a range of cells from an Excel worksheet as an image in an existing Word document, and then saving this Word document as both a Word document and a PDF file. The name both the Word file and the PDF file should get, is in a cell in the Excel worksheet.

**The problem:**
Almost everything works, except for the .pdf-file. It is generated, but when trying to open it I get an error, saying the file is unreadable.

Can someone help with this? The code I use is below - I assembled it from different examples on this and other forums (I really am a VBA beginner)...

Thank you so much!

**The Code:**

```
Sub SaveAsWord()

Dim WordApp As Object
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Dim WordDoc As Object
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Jurgen\Documents\remake.docx")

Range("C4:E19").Select
Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("here").Select
Set objSelection = WordApp.Selection
objSelection.Paste

Dim myfilename As String
myfilename = Sheets("Blad1").Range("G15")
WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\Users\Jurgen\Documents\" & myfilename & ".pdf", _
FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\Users\Jurgen\Documents\" & myfilename & ".docx", _
FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As you do not use Early Binding and it also seems that you do not use `Option Explicit` the root cause will be that `wdFormatPDF` is `0` and it should be `17`.

Either you use `Option Explicit` and `Early Binding` or you just replace the constants with the values like that

`WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\Users\Jurgen\Documents\" & myfilename & ".pdf", _
FileFormat:=17`

and

`WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:="C:\Users\Jurgen\Documents\" & myfilename & ".docx", _
FileFormat:=12`

Reading material

[Option Explict](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dim/#Is_Dim_Actually_Required)

[Early vs Late Binding](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/InterDev/EarlyvsLateBinding.htm)

[Late Binding](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/04/28/late-binding/)

[Microsoft on Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/binding-type-available-to-automation-clients)